# Ruby double iteration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm wondering if there is a sexiest way to do a double iteration, I mean, I have two iterations over the same relation like this:

```
bars = ActiveRecord::Relation [.....]
bars.each do |bar|
  do_something1(bar)
  do_something2(bar)
end
bars.each do |bar|
  do_something3(bar)
  do_something4(bar)
end
```

The obvious answer would be somethig like:

```
bars.each do |bar|
  do_something1(bar)
  do_something2(bar)
  do_something3(bar)
  do_something4(bar)
end
```

BUT in fact I REALLY do need to finish first do_something1(bar) and do_something2(bar) and THEN execute do_something3(bar) and do_something4(bar) over the same relation. Probably it is a newbie question but anything I try gets ugliest than this. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Sorry I forgot to say that I already tried also this:

```
bars.each do |bar|
  do_something1(bar)
  do_something2(bar)
end.each do |bar|
  do_something3(bar)
  so_something4(bar)
end
```

but in terms of code comprehension it's easy to understand the first one and the improvement it's just a word, that's way I didn't used it.

Comment: Can you give some more details as to what you are trying to accomplish? There may be a better approach than a double loop.

Comment: If you need to make `do_something3` and `do_something4` after everything, there is no other way I know about, just `each do... end.each`. Maybe if you explain more about what you're trying to do, there will be a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general case you can chain operations on enumerables ([list comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Ruby)) like

```
my_array.each { |e| do_something1(e) }.each { |e| do_something2(e) }
```

Since your question involves ActiveRecord there is probably a better way to do what you want than this generic example.

Comment: It's extremely rare that you'd need to do this, but if you do, this is a very concise way to do it. You may want to add a comment when using this as to why this can't be collapsed into a single `each` as it may not be obvious at first glance.

Comment: The reason why it must be this way is that do_something2(bar) creates a file on the OS and do_something3(bar) use this file to run a system command outside ruby on rails. The creation of files and the use of this files needs to be independent as soon other workers (inside rails) are using them asynchronously too.